# Unity2D Grab Object Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get this grabbing script working with my game. In The game you play as a fish in water, and fish should be able to grab and carry objects.

**Problem:**
I get that with raycast you fire The ray to certain direction which doesn't work for me in this game. This code is otherwise working fine, but I can't figure how to fix the code so that objects can be grabbed from any direction as long as in range.

**What I've tried:**
I've tried Physics2D.CircleCast, but there also you have to set the certain direction for the cast(?) Also tried OnTriggerEnter but couldn't get that working either. Is there way to cast ray to all directions(not z)? Or is there some more simple way to do this?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class grabberscript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public bool grabbed;
    RaycastHit2D hit;
    public float distance = 0f;
    public Transform holdpoint;
    public LayerMask notgrabbed;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire3"))
        {
            if (!grabbed)
            {
                Physics2D.queriesStartInColliders = false;
                
                hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.right * transform.localScale.x, distance);

                if (hit.collider != null && hit.collider.tag == "grabbable")
                {
                    grabbed = true;
                }
                
            }
            else 
            {
                grabbed = false;
            }
        }
        if (grabbed)
            hit.collider.gameObject.transform.position = holdpoint.position;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [`Physics2D.OverlapCircle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCircle.html) .. instead of casting the circle into a certain direction this only checks whether a collider lies within a circle at given center and radius. You the should not check via a tag but rather use a dedicated [**layer**](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) for all objects that shall be able to be grabbed

```
public class grabberscript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float distance = 0f;
    public Transform holdpoint;

    // Use the layer(s) for all objects that shall be grab able
    public LayerMask grabbable;

    private Transform currentlyGrabbedObject;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire3"))
        {
            if (!currentlyGrabbedObject)
            {      
                Collider2D hit = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(transform.position, distance, grabbable);

                if (hit)
                {
                    currentlyGrabbedObject = hit.transform;
                }     
            }
            else // release currently grabbed object
            {
                currentlyGrabbedObject = null;
            }               
        }

        if (currentlyGrabbedObject)
        {
            currentlyGrabbedObject.position = holdpoint.position;
        }
    }   
}
```

If you don't use a Layer as said before you would rather have to use [`Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll.html) and use the first hit matching your tag e.g. using [Linq `FirstOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault) like

```
using System.Linq;
...

Collider2D[] hits = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, distance);
  
Collider2D hit = hits.FirstOrDefault(h => h.CompareTag("grabbale");  

if (hit)
{
    currentlyGrabbedObject = hit.transform;
}
```

Comment: Thats spot on, thank you so much!!! If I can ask bit more help, how would I get the object to take players speed and direction when dropping?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use an OverlapCircle to check whether the item to grab is in range or not like this:

```
if(!grabbing)
{
    //This will save the position of all gameObjects in a specific range which are set in a or multiple specific layers
    Collider2D[] grabbedItems = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, grabRange, grabbableLayer);
}
Foreach(Collider2D item in grabbedItems)
{
   if(item.ComapreTag("grabbable"))
      {
          item.isGrabbed = true;
      }
}
```

Then in the gameObject that you intend to make grabbable, you can add a script like this:

```
public bool isGrabbed = false;
public Transform holdPoint;

void Update()
{
   if(isGrabbed)
   {
      TrackHoldPoint();
   }
}

private void TrackHoldPoint()
{
   transform.position = holdPoint.position;
}
```

Then just to be easier to set, you can add this small script to see in edit mode the range of the cirlce:

```
private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
{
    if (transform == null) return;

    Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, range);
}
```

Comment: Besides adding the complexity of more scripts for the grabbale items .. how is your main solution any different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65643180/7111561)?

Comment: Not that different indeed, still it wasn't answered when I checked earlier, so I sent my answer like you did. Just sent a couple of minutes after you.